# url script execution from php

Tags: php, html, mysql, url

I am trying to dynamically load a php form from a selected menu option, drawing the relevant form name from a mysql database and then loading the file. If relevant the actual php form is held outside the database in a directory.

I have the following line of code which I've been playing around with but to no avail

```
<a href="$submenu["form_name"]">$submenu["menu_name"]</a>
```

where $submenu is an associative array with an element called 'form_name'. This is the database field which contains the php form I'm trying to load into the 'a href'. It also contains the element called 'menu_name' which is just text. 
The array works as I've tested it by loading a generic script and drawing the row id from the database but written this way its complaining that the $submenu variable is unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="<?=$submenu["form_name"]; ?>"><?=$submenu["menu_name"]; ?></a>
```

If you're working inside `<?php ?>` code blocks, this should do it:

```
<?php
    // ......
    echo "<a href=\"{$submenu['form_name']}\">{$submenu['menu_name']}</a>";
    // ......
?>
```

Comment: This fixed the actual issue as quite rightly thought by Alejandro and not mentioned by me I was working in php blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $submenu["form_name"]; ?>"><?php echo $submenu["menu_name"]; ?></a>
```

Comment: + For not using shorthand output :)

Comment: Be sure to use `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: *"written this way its complaining that the $submenu variable is unexpected"* --- why would it say that if it's not inside a PHP code block?

Comment: Thank you - there seems to be a problem somewhere else after I drop that code in as its now complaining about an unexpected ? on that row, so whilst that should look pretty good I seem to have another problem